# How to continuously update a static file and have nginx reload it?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, frontend

I have a docker-compose setup where I deploy nginx together with my homepage that servers a static html file. I'm currently sharing a volume between the nginx proxy and the view through static-content.

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: reverse_proxy
    hostname: reverse_proxy
    depends_on:
      - engine
      - view
    volumes:
      - static-content:/www-data/
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: always

  view:
    build:
      context: github...
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        TOKEN: ${TOKEN}
    container_name: view
    command: /bin/bash -c "shadow-cljs release app"
    volumes:
      - static-content:/usr/src/view/

volumes:
  static-content:
```

i start the compose with docker-compose up and everything works fine. But what I really want to achieve is that I can have my nginx up and running and when I do changes to my webpage I want to update the static file by running `docker-compose up view`. But when I do so the updated static files are not being loaded into the nginx container.

This must be a common case? to continuously update static resources and have the changes reflect in the nginx proxy?

TLDR;
I want to have a nginx server up and running and be able to continuously deploy new updates to the static files it servers without having to take the whole compose down and up again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call docker-compose build view. docker compose up view won't rebuild the view image if it's already exists.